# Delete duplicates with specific columns as identifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, duplication

I'm required to delete all duplicate entries of a table. The duplicates are identified by two non-key values `num` (int) and `com` (varbinary(512))..

My amateur-ish SQLfoo lead me to this non-functioning query (for testing reasons I just selected the duplicates)

```
SELECT num, com FROM TableA
WHERE num, com IN
    (
        SELECT count(*) AS co FROM TableA WHERE co > 1 GROUP BY num, com
    )
```

How can I delete duplicates from `TableA` identified by `num` and `com`?

(Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2)

**edit**

from the suggestions I've tried the following two queries. TableA features ~220 entries, where ~80 are duplicates.
first @dimitars suggestion

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [num], com ORDER BY [num], com) as 'RowNumber', t1.*
    into ##TableA
    from TableA t1  

delete t1
--select t1.* 
from TableA  t1
join ##TableC t2
    on t2.[num]=t1.[num] and t2.com=t2.com
where t2.RowNumber > 1
```

resulting in every entry being deleted. And @marcelo miorellis suggestion

```
select * from TableA;
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by [num], com order by [num], com ) as Picker
    from TableA
    )
select cte 
where Picker > 1
```

which gives me

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'Picker'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'cte'.
```

Comment: @marcelo's query has `...delete cte where...`. You have `...select cte where...`

Comment: @ypercube.. correct, I first wanted to `select` 'em before `delete`ing them.. I just tried using the same with `delete` and it works as intended! thank you

Comment: @DaedalusMythos cte in the example is like a table. you need to write "select * from cte where Picker > 1" and not "select cte where Picker > 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
--=======================================================
-- delete the duplicate records from table @t
-- keeping a single unit of each
-- marcelo miorelli 24-nov-2014
--=======================================================


--=======================================================
--create a table variable and insert records in it
-- just for this example
--=======================================================
declare @t table ([num] int, com varbinary(512) )

insert into @t select 1, convert(varbinary(512), '6778981' )
insert into @t select 1, convert(varbinary(512), '6778981' )
insert into @t select 1, convert(varbinary(512), '6778982' )
insert into @t select 2, convert(varbinary(512), '6778982' )
insert into @t select 2, convert(varbinary(512), '6778982' )
insert into @t select 3, convert(varbinary(512), '6778982' )
insert into @t select 4, convert(varbinary(512), '6778982' )
insert into @t select 4, convert(varbinary(512), '6778982' )
insert into @t select 4, convert(varbinary(512), '6778982' )
insert into @t select 4, convert(varbinary(512), '6778982' )
insert into @t select 4, convert(varbinary(512), '6778983' )
insert into @t select 5, convert(varbinary(512), '6778983' )
insert into @t select 5, convert(varbinary(512), '6778983' )
insert into @t select 5, convert(varbinary(512), '6778983' )
insert into @t select 5, convert(varbinary(512), '6778983' )
insert into @t select 5, convert(varbinary(512), '6778984' )
insert into @t select 6, convert(varbinary(512), '6778984' )
insert into @t select 6, convert(varbinary(512), '6778984' )
insert into @t select 6, convert(varbinary(512), '6778985' )
insert into @t select 7, convert(varbinary(512), '6778985' )
insert into @t select 7, convert(varbinary(512), '6778985' )
insert into @t select 8, convert(varbinary(512), '6778985' )
insert into @t select 8, convert(varbinary(512), '6778985' )
insert into @t select 9, convert(varbinary(512), '6778985' )
insert into @t select 9, convert(varbinary(512), '6778986' )
insert into @t select 9, convert(varbinary(512), '6778986' )
insert into @t select 9, convert(varbinary(512), '6778986' )
insert into @t select 9, convert(varbinary(512), '6778986' )

--=======================================================
-- this is going to show the table before the deletes
--=======================================================
select * from @t


--=======================================================
-- this deletes the duplicates - leaving only 1 of each
--=======================================================
; with cte as (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by [num],com  order by [num],com ) as Picker
    from @t
    )
delete cte 
where Picker > 1


--=======================================================
-- this shows the table after the deletion - without the deletes
--=======================================================
select * from @t
```

Comment: The semi-colon `;` should really go at the end of `select * from @t;` rather than before the `with`. Get used to terminating each statement with a semi-colon. https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: thanks for this extensive answer.. but I'm unable to execute the query.. `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'Picker'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'cte'.`

Comment: @DaedalusMythos it works fine for me in sql2016 and sql 2014, I don't see why it shouldn't work for you. are you sure you have just copied and pasted the script? what version of sql server?

Answer (score 2):

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num, com  ORDER BY identity_field) as 'RowNumber', t1.*
    into ##TableA
    from TableA t1  

--delete t1
select t1.* 
from TableA t1
join ##TableA t2
    on t2.identity_field=t1.identity_field
where t2.RowNumber > 1
```

but first make backup of your table

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I assume `identity_field` is supposed to be the column that serves as a unique ID for the entries. I do not have such an identifier..

Comment: then use 'num' and 'com' or some field that is unique(if you have one)

Comment: `TableA` has ~200 entries, but selecting the ones that should be deleted (as you do in your answer) gives me 3k entries.. I'm confused.

Comment: either I'm doing something wrong or this doesn't really work.. I've executed the query above, with the `delete` and all have been deleted. But from ~200 entries 80 are duplicates..

Comment: how do you join tables?

Comment: I've edited OP and added my *copy* of your solution

Comment: try this: select * from TableA;
with cte (num,com,Picker)as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by [num], com order by [num], com ) as Picker
    from TableA
    )
select * from cte 
where Picker > 1
and check here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Why `##TableA` and not `#TableA`?

Comment: #TableA is local temporary table, ##TableA is a global temporary table.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/892366/3970854 ..why he chose to use a global temp table.. I'm not sure of, I don't see a reason to do so.